# How to create group in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-grouping

i want to create my report(rdlc) like this in the picture.I am using reportdefiniton 2005.please help how to group it like this

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/2vl0dx1.jpg]

Comment: This is doable via the wizard.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: This report was made in ssrs 2008.So i like to remake it in ssrs 2005(rdlc) but i having difficulty in grouping.need any sample like that in the picture on how do it.ty

Comment: Do you NEED to be making an rdlc?  Not an RDL?

Comment: yes, im using visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

It has been awhile since I worked with 2005 and I don't have a copy handy to give you specific instructions.

Basically you need to make two groups on your tablix. Manufacturer will be the parent group of the category field. Then use the details row to show Model and Quantity Sold.

Comment: how aboutadding line total,i want to get the total quantity sold per category.what to do?

Comment: At least in 2008 R2 there was an option to add group totals in the context menu of the tablix. But if that isn't there in 2005 you can do it in the group or table footer (depending where it needs to be). Just use the SUM() aggregate function in the expression and it will sum that field for the current scope (the group for the footer, or the entire table).